# Convert a list of tuples into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of tuples(y) that I wish to convert to a DataFrame x. There are five tuples in y. Each tuple in y has 33 elements. Element 1 in all 5 tuples is text and is the same. Element two in all five tuples is text and is the same. Element three in each tuple is text and is the same.

I'd like to first three elements in y to be the column names in the DataFrame. I want to convert the list of tuples into a 10 x 3 DataFrame. The tricky part is row 1 in the dataframe would be elements 4,5,6 in y[1], row 2 in the dataframe would be elements 7,8,9 in y[1], row 3 would be 10,11,12...etc.

y looks like this (not showing the entire list) :

```
List of tuples y                
y[0]    y[1]    y[2]    y[3]    y[4]

Formula Formula Formula Formula Formula
Phase   Phase   Phase   Phase   Phase
Value   Value   Value   Value   Value
"a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
"nxxx"  "nxxx"  "nxxx"  "nxxx"  "nxxx"
3.2 3.7 22.4    18.2    9.7
"h45"   "h45"   "h45"   "h45"   "h45"
"cacpp" "cacpp" "cacpp" "cacpp" "cacpp"
45.2    61.76   101.2   171.89  203.7
"trx"   "trx"   "trx"   "trx"   "trx"
"v2o5p" "v2o5p" "v2o5p" "v2o5p" "v2o5p"
0.24    0.81    0.97    1.2 1.98
"blnt"  "blnt"  "blnt"  "blnt"  "blnt"
"g2o3"  "g2o3"  "g2o3"  "g2o3"  "g2o3"
807.2   905.8   10089   10345   10979
```

I want to convert y into DataFrame x as follows:

```
DataFrame x     
column 1 column 2 column 3

Formula Phase   Value
"a" "nxxx"  3.2
"h45"   "cacpp" 45.2
"trx"   "v2o5p" 0.24
"blnt"  "g2o3"  807.2
"a" "nxxx"  3.7
"h45"   "cacpp" 61.76
"trx"   "v2o5p" 0.81
"blnt"  "g2o3"  905.8
"a" "nxxx"  22.4
"h45"   "cacpp" 101.2
"trx"   "v2o5p" 0.97
"blnt"  "g2o3"  10089
etc etc etc
```

I know there must be an easy way to iterate through the list of tuples. But new to Pandas and relatively new to Python so I'm struggling with a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need:
1) remove first 3 element of each tuple (just need one as column header)
2) `concatenate` all elements in `y`
3) `reshape` to 3 columns
All these can be achieved with `numpy` which you must be familiar if you are using `pandas`

```
#Step 1) and 2) above.
In [83]: data = np.concatenate ([z[3:] for z in y])

#reshape
In [84]: data = data.reshape(-1, 3)

#Now data is a numpy array which looks what you need:
In [85]: data
Out[85]: 
array([['a', 'nxxx', '3.2'],
       ['h45', 'cacpp', '45.2'],
       ['trx', 'v2o5p', '0.24'],
       ['blnt', 'g2o3', '807.2'],
       ['a', 'nxxx', '3.7'],
       ['h45', 'cacpp', '61.76'],
       ['trx', 'v2o5p', '0.81'],
       ['blnt', 'g2o3', '905.8'],
       ['a', 'nxxx', '22.4'],
       ['h45', 'cacpp', '101.2'],
       ['trx', 'v2o5p', '0.97'],
       ['blnt', 'g2o3', '10089'],
       ['a', 'nxxx', '18.2'],
       ['h45', 'cacpp', '171.89'],
       ['trx', 'v2o5p', '1.2'],
       ['blnt', 'g2o3', '10345'],
       ['a', 'nxxx', '9.7'],
       ['h45', 'cacpp', '203.7'],
       ['trx', 'v2o5p', '1.98'],
       ['blnt', 'g2o3', '10979']], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

You can put `data` into a `pandas DataFrame`

```
In [86]: df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns=y[0][:3])

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
   Formula  Phase   Value
0        a   nxxx     3.2
1      h45  cacpp    45.2
2      trx  v2o5p    0.24
3     blnt   g2o3   807.2
4        a   nxxx     3.7
5      h45  cacpp   61.76
6      trx  v2o5p    0.81
7     blnt   g2o3   905.8
8        a   nxxx    22.4
9      h45  cacpp   101.2
10     trx  v2o5p    0.97
11    blnt   g2o3   10089
12       a   nxxx    18.2
13     h45  cacpp  171.89
14     trx  v2o5p     1.2
15    blnt   g2o3   10345
16       a   nxxx     9.7
17     h45  cacpp   203.7
18     trx  v2o5p    1.98
19    blnt   g2o3   10979
```

Comment: This looks really great but still getting an error....

def phs_tab(y):
        data = np.concatenate ([z[3:] for z in y])
        data = data.reshape(-1, 3)
        df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns=y[0][:3])
        print df

phs_tab(y)


 data = data.reshape(-1, 3)

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: try `for z in y: print len(z)` to check if all y's have expected length?

Comment: This step gave me the error:

data = data.reshape(-1, 3)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some dummy data:

```
In [122]: y1 = ('Formula', 'Phase', 'Value', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
In [123]: y2 = ('Formula', 'Phase', 'Value', 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
In [124]: y = [y1, y2]
```

And using this 'grouper' recipe from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) to iterate by groups.

```
In [125]: from itertools import izip_longest

In [126]: def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
     ...:     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
     ...:     return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Then you could do something like this?  The `grouper(y_tuple[3:], 3)` iterates over the tuple in groups of 3, excluding the first 3 elements.

```
In [127]: columns = y[0][:3]

In [128]: data = []
     ...: for y_tuple in y:
     ...:     for group_of_3 in grouper(y_tuple[3:], 3):
     ...:         data.append(list(group_of_3))
     ...:         

In [129]: data
Out[129]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

In [130]: pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
Out[130]: 
   Formula  Phase  Value
0        1      2      3
1        4      5      6
2        7      8      9
3       10     11     12
```